# Paint ticks on custom QProgressBar in Pyside

Tags: python, pyside, qprogressbar

I'm trying to paint some ticks in my custom progressbar but I'm not clear on why the line isn't showing up at all?

[image]

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append('Z:\\pipeline\\site-packages')
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class QProgressBarPro(QtGui.QProgressBar):

    progressClicked = QtCore.Signal()
    progressChanging = QtCore.Signal()
    progressChanged = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QProgressBarPro, self).__init__(parent)
        self.default_value = 50.0
        self.lmb_pressed = False
        self.setFormat('%p')
        self.setRange(0.0, 100.0)
        self.stepEnabled = True
        self.step = 5
        self.setToolTip('<strong>Press+Hold+Ctrl</strong> for percise values<br><strong>Right-Click</strong> to reset default value')

    def step_round(self, x, base=5):
        return int(base * round(float(x)/base))

    def set_value_from_cursor(self, xpos):
        width = self.frameGeometry().width()
        percent = float(xpos) / width
        val = self.maximum() * percent

        if self.stepEnabled:
            modifiers = QtGui.QApplication.keyboardModifiers()
            if modifiers != QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
                val = self.step_round(val, self.step)

        self.setValue(val)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.progressClicked.emit()
        mouse_button = event.button()

        if mouse_button == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self.setValue(self.default_value)
        else:
            xpos = event.pos().x()
            self.set_value_from_cursor(xpos)
            self.lmb_pressed = True
        self.progressChanging.emit()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.lmb_pressed = False
        self.progressChanged.emit()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.lmb_pressed:
            xpos = event.pos().x()
            self.set_value_from_cursor(xpos)
            self.progressChanging.emit()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.drawLine(10, 0, 10, 10)
        QtGui.QProgressBar.paintEvent(self, event)


# DEMO
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.ui_progress = QProgressBarPro()
        self.ui_progress.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.ui_progress.setValue(10)

        gdl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        gdl.addWidget(self.ui_progress)
        self.setLayout(gdl)

        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tooltips')    
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `paintEvent` function.

I wrote a first approach that provides same result as in your image:

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    QtGui.QProgressBar.paintEvent(self, event)
    painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    # Set gray color
    brush.setColor(QtGui.QColor(204,204,204))
    painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(brush, 2, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine,QtCore.Qt.RoundCap))
    #print(str(self.width())+","+str(self.height()))
    progressbarwidth = self.width()
    progressbarheight = self.height()
    ## Drawing one vertical line each 1/5
    painter.drawLine(progressbarwidth*1/5, 0, progressbarwidth*1/5, progressbarheight)
    painter.drawLine(progressbarwidth*2/5, 0, progressbarwidth*2/5, progressbarheight)
    painter.drawLine(progressbarwidth*3/5, 0, progressbarwidth*3/5, progressbarheight)
    painter.drawLine(progressbarwidth*4/5, 0, progressbarwidth*4/5, progressbarheight)
```

The achieved outcome is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pASeY.png).